# Reverse a list in python based on condition

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list in a way that .log should be the first file and .gz file should be in a descending order

```
my_list = [
     '/abc/a.log.1.gz',
     '/abc/a.log',
     '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.29.gz'
]
```

expected_result:

```
my_list = ['/abc/a.log',
        '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.2.gz'
        '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

`reversed(mylist)` is also not getting me the desired solution.

Comment: Do the numbered, zipped files only have the numbers you've shown, or could others, like 10 get mixed in (sorting between 1 and 2 in your current code, but intended to be between 2 and 30)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sorted` with a custom `key` function and `reverse=True`:

```
print(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x.endswith('log'), x), reverse=True))
#['/abc/spa/a.log',
# '/abc/spa/a.log.30.gz',
# '/abc/spa/a.log.2.gz',
# '/abc/spa/a.log.1.gz']
```

---

Based on the updated question, it seems like you are trying to sort file names. I would recommend using `os.path` to manipulate these strings.

First you can use `os.path.splitext` split out the extension to compare between `.log` or `.gz`. Then strip off the extension again to get the file number, and convert it to an integer.

For example:

```
import os

def get_sort_keys(filepath):
    split_file_path = os.path.splitext(filepath)
    sort_key = (split_file_path[1], *os.path.splitext(split_file_path[0]))
    return (sort_key[0], sort_key[1], int(sort_key[2].strip(".")) if sort_key[2] else 0)

print(sorted(my_list, key=get_sort_keys, reverse=True))
#['/abc/a.log',
# '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
# '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

In this version, I am not explicitly checking for `endswith("log")` as before, but I am relying on the fact that the `log` extension will sort after `gz` lexicographically.

Comment: Nice use of `x.endswith('log')`, great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. ANd if I want to sort gz in ascending order that is log.1.gz...,log.30.gz and now also keeping .log file at the top. How we can do that?

Comment: @user15051990 that's a simple change. Just add a negative sign in front of the `int` so the integers sort ascending. The last line of `get_sort_keys()` would become: `return (sort_key[0], sort_key[1], -int(sort_key[2].strip(".")) if sort_key[2] else 0`

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple extension then assign rank in dictionary to have more flexibility

```
my_list = ['/abc/spa/a.log.1.gz',
 '/abc/spa/a.log',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.30.tar',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.30.gz',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.2.gz']

rank={'log':1,'gz':2,'tar':3}    # 'tar' is optional here
sorted(my_list,key = lambda x : (-rank.get(x.rsplit('.')[-1],0), x),reverse=True)
```

this will give

```
['/abc/spa/a.log',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.30.gz',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.2.gz',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.1.gz',
 '/abc/spa/a.log.30.tar']
```

For your updated question

```
my_list = [
     '/abc/a.log.1.gz',
     '/abc/a.log',
     '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.29.gz'
]
rank={'log':1,'gz':2,'tar':3}    # 'tar' is optional here
sorted(my_list,key = lambda x : (-rank.get(x.rsplit('.',1)[-1]), int(x.split('.')[-2]) if x.split('.')[-2].isdigit() else 0),reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['/abc/a.log',
 '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.29.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.14.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.12.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.10.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.8.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
 '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

Comment: This makes sense. I would do something like `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x.rsplit(".", 1)[-1], x), reverse=True)` if the goal was to first sort by extension, then filename.